# Enable Inline edit for non editable cells display a lock icon

Tags: formula-field, inlineeditsupport, inline

I have created a formula field. After saving the record I am able to see the formula field with data and I am unable to in line edit from there. I would like to enable inline edit for the fields which display lock icon. Suggest me anyway that I can achieve that.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot edit formula fields. Formula fields are meant to calculate whenever the record is referenced(detail page view or soql query). Check document to know more about formula fields here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas

Comment: Apart from the accepted answer, note that fields of types such as long text area are not editable on the list view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit or inline edit some fields. Roll up summary, formulas, most audit fields, and some special system fields, like owner fields, can't be edited inline. There's no exhaustive list of non-inline-editable fields, but experience over time should be your guide. Also, most of the fields I just mentioned can't be edited at all, even though the API.